# Why does my Corel Painter eraser erase only squares?

Tags: image-manipulation

I´m using Corel Painter XI. No matter if I use my mouse or mousepen, even trackpad... the eraser tool only erase squares... I have the standard properties for the eraser (freehand strokes, soft mode)... and nothing just ugly squares...

[image]

It happens with the Eraser variants too (watercolor eraser diffuse, for example)

Apparently, [there is a bug](http://painterfactory.com/forums/p/2509/13184.aspx) with the eraser tool, but does not officially documented.

At this rate, my trial period will expires without actually test this interesting software.

Comment: I was not able to recreate this bug.

Comment: @Sathya: Neither do I. The original file has one so called 'watercolor layer' in wich the bug exists. The bottom layer is a normal one, without bug. I created a new file with watercolor layer, but I can erase without a problem. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is typical and it happens to me every once in a while. Like Edgar said, its only a layer problem. Your file is fine, all you have to do is right click on the layer and select commit. You should be able to erase normally on that layer. Hope this helps many people, I just tried it a few minutes ago and I was able to erase a shadow I was working on. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel. I have not tried this solution, but the next time I get in trouble, I will check.